# Win32 menu bitmap transparency after selecting item

Tags: c, winapi, bitmap, menu, transparency

I am trying to add icon image to context menu of my win32 application

Here is my code

```
hMenu = LoadMenuIndirect( LoadResourceLang( RT_MENU, resID ) );

hMenu = ::GetSubMenu( hMenu, 0 );

HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImage((HMODULE)g_hInst,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BM_PAUSE), IMAGE_BITMAP, 16, 16, LR_CREATEDIBSECTION );

SetMenuItemBitmaps( hMenu, 2, MF_BITMAP|MF_BYPOSITION, hBitmap, hBitmap );

::TrackPopupMenu( hMenu, TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON, point.x, point.y, 0, m_hWnd, 0 );
```

Everything works fine when menu first shown.

But when the cursor hovers over menu item and selection rectangle is drawn, the bitmap is redrawn incorrectly, the transparency is ignored.

Here are the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Any suggestion how to fix this?

Comment: What is the exact bitmap format? How many BPP?

Comment: bitmap format is 32 bits

Answer (score 3):

These bitmaps are only supposed to be used for simple checkmarks etc. and **must** be monochrome bitmaps. Your usage seems fine as long as you only need one color.

> [The selected and clear bitmaps should be monochrome](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647998%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The system uses the Boolean AND operator to combine bitmaps with the menu so that the white part becomes transparent and the black part becomes the menu-item color. If you use color bitmaps, the results may be undesirable.

Ideally you should generate the bitmap on the fly so it matches [CYMENUCHECK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx).

On Windows Vista and later it is also possible to [assign a 32bpp image](https://web.archive.org/web/20080221005210/http://shellrevealed.com/blogs/shellblog/archive/2007/02/06/Vista-Style-Menus_2C00_-Part-1-_2D00_-Adding-icons-to-standard-menus.aspx) to a menu item without doing owner-draw...

Comment: I tried SetMenuItemInfo with MIIM_BITMAP and hbmpItem set. And got the same result.

Comment: For a simple pause image you should use a simple 1bpp bmp image. 32bpp images need some extra work, you need to make sure the alpha channel is correct.

Comment: I tried monochrome image. Now it displayed without transparency, just black image on white rectangle. It does not looks like "white part becomes transparent and the black part becomes the menu-item color"  :(

Comment: oops forget to add LR_MONOCHROME to LoadImage call. Now it works. Thanks